# Two JQuery functions, whichever is loaded second stops the first from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, ready

I have two jQuery document.ready functions, one is for a pop-up, the other is for a cookie notification banner. 
The problem I am encountering is when I load these separately whichever one I load second stops the first from working.
For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        jQuery("#bookdirectlink").click(function() {
            jQuery("#bookdirectp").show();
        });
        jQuery(".close").click(function() {
            jQuery("#bookdirectp").hide();
        });
    }

    );
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(
     function() {
     $('.cookie-message').cookieBar({ closeButton : '.my-close-button' });


     });

</script>
```

The second script then works and hides the cookie bar when the button is clicked, but the first script doesn't work. The reverse is true if I swap the scripts around. 
I've also tried combining the two into one ready statement, ie:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        jQuery("#bookdirectlink").click(function() {
            jQuery("#bookdirectp").show();
        });
        jQuery(".close").click(function() {
            jQuery("#bookdirectp").hide();
        });
         $('.cookie-message').cookieBar({ closeButton : '.my-close-button' });
    }

    );
</script>
```

But then none of the functions work.

The cookie bar runs from a script that I am loading in the header:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/dist/js/jquery.cookieBar.js"/>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

This is the html for the cookie banner:

```
<div class="cookie-message">
    <p>We use cookies, including those by third parties, to improve our services, show you advertisements based on your preferences, perform statistical analysis on our users' browsing behaviour and simplify the interaction with social networks. If you continue browsing, we will assume that you agree with their use.</p><p> You can obtain further information here. <a href="/tcs-and-cookies/" class="privacylink">Privacy Policy</a></p> <a class="my-close-button" href>Accept</a>
</div>
```

And the html for the pop up:

```
<div id="directcontainer">

            <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
            <?php if(get_field('heading', 'option')){ ?><h2><?php the_field('heading', 'option'); ?></h2> <?php } ?>
            <?php if(get_field('main_text', 'option')){ ?><p><?php the_field('main_text', 'option'); ?></p> <?php } ?>
            <?php if(get_field('small_text', 'option')){ ?><p><span><?php the_field('small_text', 'option'); ?></span></p> <?php } ?>

<?php if(get_field('booking_button_link', 'option')){ ?><a href="<?php the_field('booking_button_link', 'option'); ?>" target="_blank" class="button"><?php if(get_field('booking_button_text', 'option')){ ?><?php the_field('booking_button_text', 'option'); ?></a> <?php } ?><?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: any errors in your console? There's no reason, in theory, why this wouldn't work AFAIK. Although you are switching between `jQuery` and `$`...any particular reason you did that? Is `$` set to mean something else in your page perhaps?

Comment: Your second code snippet should work fine. It's likely that you have an error somewhere. I'd suggest checking the console.

Comment: Is there any errors  in the console? I am guessing there is some compatibility issue. Instead of document.ready, can you try loading it as an IIFE with $ as input and see if it works?

Comment: @Adyson I created the first script using jQuery, but the cookie bar is taken from github and copied and pasted which is why it is using $. Could that be a problem?

I'm not seeing any errors in the console. 

How would I load it as an IIFE?

Comment: The IIFE part wasn't me, not sure what that is. There's no obvious reason why `$` would be a problem unless something else in your page was already using that shortcut. If you're not getting errors it seems a bit unlikely. It's also a bit odd that the two pieces of code interfere. Can you show us the relevant HTML please, for the various elements this code targets (the cookie bar HTML, and the HTML for the other elements referenced by your two click event handlers?

Comment: OK sure, I've updated my question with the html for the two elements

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x357jpyk/3/ ...the cookie part works fine. The other bit doesn't because you haven't got any element with the id "bookdirectp", and no element with the id "bookdirectlink". If you did, it would also work nicely: http://jsfiddle.net/x357jpyk/7/

Comment: My apologies, I cut cut off one of the divs in my code snippet. 
The issue has actually been resolved, I didn't close my script call correctly! I had `<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/dist/js/jquery.cookieBar.js"/>` 
instead of:
 `<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/dist/js/jquery.cookieBar.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake:
 I had 
`<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/dist/js/jquery.cookieBar.js"/>` 
instead of:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/dist/js/jquery.cookieBar.js"></script>
```